# REDIS python search queries

Tags: python, redis

I have pairs of key,value. Keys and values are both unique. Could redis hash them both so I would have O(1) time queries?

Comment: See if this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikeyk/1329319) helps you,  which has been discussed here [Instagram Engineering](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs)